# piping obj keys list with list head in Ramda

Tags: functional-programming, pipe, ramda.js

How do I pipe this?

R.keys(obj) returns a list
R.head should get first item of list
what I'm I missing?

```
const obj = {f: "hi"}     
const keysList = R.keys(obj);
const head = R.head(keysList);

const myPipe = R.pipe(keysList , head ) //?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R.pipe expects a list of functions, and returns a new function. When that function is called, any parameters passed to this function, are passed to the 1st function in the pipe, the result of the 1st function is passed to the next, and so on.

In your case, you try to create a function that looks like this:

```
o => R.head(R.keys(o))
```

This is equivalent to:

```
R.pipe(R.keys, R.head)
```

Example:

```js
const obj = {f: "hi"}     

const myPipe = R.pipe(R.keys, R.head)

const result = myPipe(obj)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```